# How can I customize garbage collection in LeakCanary 2.10?

Tags: leakcanary

I'd like to use more thorough garbage collection than the LeakCanary default, prior to marking an object detained. This seemed to help with avoiding spurious Service-related leaks in earlier LeakCanary versions, where it was trivial to override the garbage collection approach via configuration.

How can I do this now, in LeakCanary 2.10?